# PL/SQL How to set value before Raise_application_error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm creating a trigger to set off if prixHeure < 0. Im new to triggers.

My problem is that Id like to do two things if prixHeure < 0 but I cant make it work.
To set the value where it was going to be negative to 0 and then do a raise_applicaton_error() to stop and print a message.

Ive made either work but not both at the same time. Is it possible?

Also Im getting an error `PLS-00103: Symbole "UPDATE" found` when I spool my whole table but if I run my code, trigger first and then the tests, I dont get the error. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
--TRIGGER2
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER restrictionTarifHoraire
BEFORE UPDATE ON RESSOURCESPROJET FOR EACH ROW
--DECLARE taux_horaire RESSOURCESPROJET.prixHeure%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.prixHeure > (:old.prixHeure * 1.5)
    THEN
        :New.prixHeure := :old.prixHeure ;
        END IF;
    IF  :NEW.prixHeure < 0
    THEN
       :New.prixheure := 0 ;
    END IF;
    IF  :old.prixHeure = 0
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'PrixHeure < 0, le nouveau prixHoraire est de 0 pour cet employé') ;
    END IF;
END;

--TEST2.1
UPDATE RESSOURCESPROJET
SET prixHeure = 48
WHERE ressourcesprojet.idEmploye=5465;

--TEST2.2
UPDATE RESSOURCESPROJET
SET prixHeure = -1
WHERE ressourcesprojet.idEmploye=5465;
```

Comment: you need a / after the CREATE and UPDATE statements if running this from sqlplus

Comment: Your error condition only happens if `old.prixHeure = 0`. Do either of those rows have 0 in that column?

Comment: If the code raises an error, update process will be interrupted. It's pointless to set any value during `raise_application_error` because you will not see it or be able to use it anywhere. Also please note that condition on `:old` to raise an exception is quite strange: you cannot do anything with the data already stored in the table, so complain about `:old` will prevent any change

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is a warning you can issue. But Oracle doesn't support warnings on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, only errors. So either a statement runs fine or an error is raised and the statement fails. RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR makes the statement fail, so the update doesn't take place.